# Printing the last column of a line in a file

Tags: file, awk, tail

I have a file that is constantly being written to/updated. I want to find the last line containing a particular word, then print the last column of that line.

The file looks something like this. More A1/B1/C1 lines will be appended to it over time.

```
A1 123 456
B1 234 567
C1 345 678
A1 098 766
B1 987 6545
C1 876 5434
```

I tried to use

```
tail -f file | grep A1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

to print the value 766, but nothing is output.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You don't see anything, because of buffering. The output is shown, when there are enough lines or end of file is reached. `tail -f` means wait for more input, but there are no more lines in `file` and so the pipe to `grep` is never closed.

If you omit `-f` from `tail` the output is shown immediately:

```
tail file | grep A1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

---

@EdMorton is right of course. [Awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) can search for `A1` as well, which shortens the command line to

```
tail file | awk '/A1/ {print $NF}'
```

or without tail, showing the last column of all lines containing `A1`

```
awk '/A1/ {print $NF}' file
```

---

Thanks to @MitchellTracy's comment, [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) might miss the record containing `A1` and thus you get no output at all. This may be solved by switching `tail` and `awk`, searching first through the file and only then show the last line:

```
awk '/A1/ {print $NF}' file | tail -n1
```

Comment: You never need grep+awk since awk can do it's own RE comparison. "grep A1 | awk '{print $NF}'" should just be "awk '/A1/{print $NF}'". Also, if you aren't using tail -f then you don't need tail at all, yoiu can just do: awk '/A1/{f=$NF} END{print f}' file

Comment: This isn't quite right, as the column may not appear in the window that raw `tail` gives you. Unless you know it is going to appear with a certain frequency, it would be safer to `awk '/A1/ {print $NF}' file | tail -n1`.

Answer (score 41):

To print the last column of a line just use $(NF):

```
awk '{print $(NF)}'
```

Comment: Why not just `$NF`?

Answer (score 14):

One way using `awk`:

```
tail -f file.txt | awk '/A1/ { print $NF }'
```

Comment: I thought that was the right solution to the posted problem (+1!) but now I see I don't understand the question. The OP wants the last field from the LAST LINE of the file, but there is no LAST LINE if you're using tail -f. Maybe he means the last line CURRENTLY in the file, in which case see one of my other comments.

Comment: Very good and simple. Thumbs up. Thumbs down for `awk`'s cryptic syntax :)

Comment: awk's syntax might appear cryptic nowadays, but it was really ahead of its time. In 1977 (when awk was born), C was a kindergartener (at 5yo), and C++ a glimmer in Bjarne's eye. It's the only language I use where it's normal to include your entire program as a command-line parameter! I might be biased, though, since I've always been a bit awk-ward. ;)

Answer (score 12):

You can do this without awk with just some pipes.

```
tac file | grep -m1 A1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

Comment: This solves your problem, but it doesn't really use awk. Hope it's good enough for you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this works?

```
grep A1 file | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the actual issue here, but might help some one: I was doing `awk "{print $NF}"`, note the wrong quotes. Should be `awk '{print $NF}'`, so that the shell doesn't expand `$NF`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of it in `awk`:

```
<file awk '$1 ~ /A1/ {m=$NF} END {print m}'
```

Comment: You don't need split() and an array, just save the last field and print that: awk '/A1/{f=$NF} END{print f}' file

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl

```
$ cat rayne.txt
A1 123 456
B1 234 567
C1 345 678
A1 098 766
B1 987 6545
C1 876 5434


$ perl -lane ' /A1/ and $x=$F[2] ; END { print "$x" } ' rayne.txt
766

$
```

Comment: Looks too complicated, just do `perl -lane 'print $F[2] if /A1/' rayne.txt`

Comment: @Hi-Angel..the question asks for last occurrence of A1. your answer will print all matches.. btw if you like my answer, pls upvote it

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F " " '($1=="A1") {print $NF}' FILE | tail -n 1`

Use `awk` with field separator **-F** set to a space " ".

Use the *pattern* `$1=="A1"` and *action* `{print $NF}`, this will print the last field in every record where the first field is "A1". Pipe the result into tail and use the `-n 1` option to only show the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this on the file:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' filename
```

and you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score -3):

`ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n1`

Comment: How is this even related to the OP's question?