# Print everything in column of file bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, grep

My file looks like this

```
ID     Done       Have     ETA      Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
  2   100%   858.1 MB    Done     56.0     0.0    1.2  Seeding      lubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

What I need to do is write a grep/awk string that will give me everything under the last column "Name"

Any ideas?

Comment: `awk '{print $NF}' file`

Comment: Possibly better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13046167/2088135

Comment: The problem is that each part of the filename is a seperate column. For the example above where the filename is joined together that works perfectly. When the filename is split up (e.g. Kali Linux 2016 amd64). This will only print "kali"

Comment: How can you tell when any white space is within a field ("column") vs between fields? Are your fields separated by tab or some other white space character which cannot appear within a field or are the fields fixed-width (always start/end at a specific character count) or something else? Also, do you want to print the value of the last field or the value of the field whose value on the first line is "Name" and that field may not always be the last one?

Answer (score 0):

To print the last field for each line after the first:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $NF}'
```