# Files with same name

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, uniq

I have used find and saved the result to file.txt file. Now I want to check files with same name sorted highest count first.
e.g.:

```
/Volumes/1 drive/foo
/Volumes/1 drive/bar
/Volumes/1 drive/foo2
/Volumes/2 drive/foo
/Volumes/2 drive/bar2
/Volumes/3 drive/1/foo
/Volumes/3 drive/2/bar
```

I am running this command:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $NR}' | uniq -c | sort
```

But awk output doesn't work correctly, it prints only first line:

```
Volumes
1 drive
foo
```

EDIT: The output should be:

```
3 foo
2 bar
1 foo2
1 bar2
```

Comment: What is the expected output for your shown samples?

Comment: 3 foo \n 2 bar \n 1 foo2 \n 1 bar2 (sorry about line break in answer).

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Replace `$NR` by `$NF`. Sort before unique-ing (`uniq` works only on sorted files), and avoid `cat | awk`, it's an anti-pattern. Simply `awk '...' file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to delete the paths and only keep the part after the last slash, you can do it with `sed` like this: `sed 's|.*/||'`.

Note that you need a sorted column for `uniq -c` to work. So then if you want its output sorted as well, you need two `sort` calls:

```
> sed 's|.*/||' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      3 foo
      2 bar
      1 foo2
      1 bar2
```

---

If you want to use `awk`, then you probably need `$NF` and not `$NR`:

```
awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

This use of `awk` is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046224/1258041).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this awk one-liner:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{a[$NF]++} END{for (x in a)print a[x],x}' file.txt|sort -nr
3 foo
2 bar
1 foo2
1 bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {m,n,g}awk '
 { __[$!++NF]++ } END { ___=_+=_=length(FS)
 
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
                   
    for (_ in __) {
         printf("%\047*.f %s\n",___,__[_],_) } }' FS='^.+[/]' OFS= \
                                           \
  | gsort -nr  # pipe over to sort for any non-gnu awk

       3 foo
       2 bar
       1 foo2
       1 bar2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xargs -I "{}" basename "{}" <file|sort|uniq -c
      2 bar
      1 bar2
      3 foo
      1 foo2

$ xargs -I "{}" basename "{}" <file|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/^ *//'|sort -nr
3 foo
2 bar
1 foo2
1 bar2
```

Using find as input

```
find /your/path -type f -print0|xargs -0 basename -a|sort|uniq -c|sed 's/^ *//'|sort -nr
```